# How do you get rid of faded component designators after copying and pasting components in Altium?

Tags: altium

When copying and pasting a component that already has a designator in an Altium schematic document and assigning it a new designator, the designator from the original part still shows up as a ghost, as shown in the picture.

[image: example]

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Who ya gonna call.....

Comment: usually this will go away after you recompile the design a few times. But if you are using repeat-blocks and multichannel techniques, the master sheet will display the designators of the child sheets

Comment: I think you misunderstand the compilation and board level annotation processes. Altium has some good documentation online you should read first. It will help you more than any piecemeal answers will.

Answer (score 2):

In 'old' Altium (17 and older): Do a recompile.

In 'new' Altium (upto 21): DXP Preferences -> Schematic -> Compiler then in the 'Compiled Names Expansion' section uncheck 'Designators' then press the Apply button at the bottom. Then re-check 'Designators' and push Apply again.

... and all the ghost designators just got busted.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do anything to it. They do not show up in any exports and do not affect the design in any noticeable way. All it is doing is showing the expanded compiled name of the designator. To get rid of it you should be able to go to your DXP preferences --> Schematic --> Compiler and under "Compiled Names Expansion" change the dropdown next to "Designators" from "Display superscript" to "Don't display" (or whatever the actual text is -- I can't remember off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out how to get rid of this. However, I advise you *not* to get rid of this!

Designators will be displayed grayed-out when the schematic was changed but not yet copied over to your PCB layout. You can therefore match the components to your current design even though the designator numbering was changed.

It will go away once you import the schematic changes into the design. Altium is trying to help you here, for which you paid handsomely. Let it help you!